# angular 4 custom validator is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm working on angular 4 and created a custom validator for cgpa validation (if the cgpa is less tahn 2.0 or greater than 4.0) in the component.ts file but its not triggering but the predefined Validators.required is working properly.

Cgpa Validator:

```
 function ValidCgpa(cgpa: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean}  {
  let num = Number(cgpa);

  if(num < 2.0 || num > 4.0)  {
    return {invalidCgpa: true};
  }
 }
```

Custom Cgpa Validator Calling

```
this.educationalDetailsForm = new FormGroup({
  cgpa: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidCgpa]))
});
```

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" formControlName="cgpa" placeholder="CGPA">

<div *ngIf="educationalDetailsForm.hasError('ValidCgpa','cgpa') && educationalDetailsForm.get('cgpa').touched">
   CGPA must be greater than 2.0 and less than 4.0
</div>
```

Comment: Number(cgpa) should be Number(cgpa.value), or simpler: +cgpa.value. Adding logs in the code, or using the debugger makes that very easy to find. A validator is summposed to return null, not undefined, when there is no error, too.

Comment: thats right, but he says that the validator isn't being invoked, so the line is wrong, but that is not the problem

Comment: Other than that, the code is correct. If it's not invoked, then a complete example is needed. See http://plnkr.co/edit/XxZw1icOBLUDLtHgVy7V?p=preview. But my guess is that the OP *thinks* it's not invoked because the error message doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you implemented the validator is wrong, try something like this (not tested):

```
export function ValidCgpa(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const num = Number(cgpa.value);
    if(num < 2.0 || num > 4.0)  {
       return {invalidCgpa: true};
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

Custom Validator

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateGpa(control: AbstractControl) {
  const num = Number(control.value);
  if (num < 0 || num > 4.0) {
    return { invalidGpa: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

In html

```
<h1>Type here and Check</h1>
<input type="text"  [formControl]="gpa">
<br>
<div *ngIf="gpa.errors?.invalidGpa">Invalid GPA value</div>
```

In typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidateGpa } from './validators/valid-gpa.validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  gpa = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, ValidateGpa]);
}
```

Try this [example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-valid-gpa)

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer doing the validations on the HTML direct as follows:

```
<input type="number" required name="cgpa" [(ngModel)]="cgpaValue" #cgpa="ngModel">

<div *ngIf="cgpa.touched && (!cpga.valid || cpga.value < 2 || cpga.value > 4 )">
    CGPA must be greater than 2.0 and less than 4.0 
</div>
```